# Using glmer logistic regression model to predict point at which continuous variable reaches specific probability?

Tags: r, prediction, predict, mixed-models

I have a dataset relating to a memory experiment, with the factors participant, box, trial number (trial), trialblock (block), age group and sex as categorical variables, interval as a continuous variable, and a binary outcome (SuccessBinary), as illustrated by this smaller example dataset:

```
data <- structure(list(Participant = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), 
        Block = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
        Trial = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
        13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
        6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
        19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
        13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
        6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
        19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
        13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
        6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
        19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
        13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
        6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
        19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
        13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), Box = structure(c(4L, 
        3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
        4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
        3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
        4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
        3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
        4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
        "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), Interval = c(240L, 120L, 
        0L, 60L, 120L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 0L, 240L, 30L, 240L, 60L, 
        30L, 120L, 60L, 0L, 240L, 120L, 30L, 0L, 240L, 120L, 30L, 
        240L, 0L, 60L, 240L, 30L, 240L, 30L, 120L, 60L, 120L, 0L, 
        60L, 120L, 60L, 0L, 60L, 30L, 240L, 120L, 60L, 0L, 240L, 
        0L, 240L, 120L, 60L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 120L, 240L, 120L, 
        60L, 30L, 240L, 120L, 0L, 60L, 120L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 0L, 
        240L, 30L, 240L, 60L, 30L, 120L, 60L, 0L, 240L, 120L, 30L, 
        0L, 240L, 120L, 30L, 240L, 0L, 60L, 240L, 30L, 240L, 30L, 
        120L, 60L, 120L, 0L, 60L, 120L, 60L, 0L, 60L, 30L, 240L, 
        120L, 60L, 0L, 240L, 0L, 240L, 120L, 60L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 
        120L, 240L, 120L, 60L, 30L, 240L, 120L, 0L, 60L, 120L, 30L, 
        0L, 30L, 60L, 0L, 240L, 30L, 240L, 60L, 30L, 120L, 60L, 0L, 
        240L, 120L, 30L, 0L, 240L, 120L, 30L, 240L, 0L, 60L, 240L, 
        30L, 240L, 30L, 120L, 60L, 120L, 0L, 60L, 120L, 60L, 0L, 
        60L, 30L, 240L, 120L, 60L, 0L, 240L, 0L, 240L, 120L, 60L, 
        30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 120L, 240L, 120L, 60L, 30L), SuccessBinary = c(1L, 
        0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
        1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
        1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
        0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
        1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
        AgeGroup = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1-5", "11-15", "6-10"
        ), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", 
        "M"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -180L), spec = structure(list(
        cols = structure(list(Dog = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), Block = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), Trial = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), Box = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), Interval = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), Visit = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), Outcome = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), SuccessBinary = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), Age = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
        "collector")), AgeGroup = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), Sex = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector"))), .Names = c("Dog", "Block", "Trial", "Box", 
        "Interval", "Visit", "Outcome", "SuccessBinary", "Age", "AgeGroup", 
        "Sex")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
        "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Participant", "Block", "Trial", 
    "Box", "Interval", "SuccessBinary", "AgeGroup", "Sex"))
```

I have created a mixed-effects binary logistic regression model using the glmer package to analyse it as such:

```
model <- glmer(SuccessBinary ~ Interval + Block + Box + Trial + AgeGroup + Sex +
           + (1 | Participant),
           data = data, family = binomial, nAGQ=1)
```

And used the summary() function to assess the significance of each factor, giving (for the original, longer dataset):

```
Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    1.049030   0.391677   2.678   0.0074 ** 
Interval      -0.008192   0.001142  -7.171 7.43e-13 ***
Block2         0.206471   0.212581   0.971   0.3314    
Block3         0.223291   0.224761   0.993   0.3205    
Box2          -0.521759   0.251940  -2.071   0.0384 *  
Box3          -0.236628   0.248939  -0.951   0.3418    
Box4           0.191712   0.248141   0.773   0.4398    
Trial         -0.038932   0.015401  -2.528   0.0115 *  
AgeGroup11-15 -0.413951   0.374989  -1.104   0.2696    
AgeGroup6-10  -0.116284   0.338754  -0.343   0.7314    
SexM           0.159609   0.306192   0.521   0.6022
```

So there is a significant effect of interval (my main variable of interest), box 2 and trial (I have also calculated odds ratios and CIs – not shown).

What I now want to find out is how to predict the interval at which the probability of success reaches 0.25 (which is the value expected by chance in this experiment).

Additionally, If it is possible and valid to do so, I would also like to check whether the probability of success at each measured interval significantly differs from 0.25 (I am aware that I would have to create a new model with interval as a categorical rather than continuous variable in order to do this, but other than that don't know how to do it.)

Thanks in advance for any help and advice!